# Cannot make an input type=date required

Tags: angular, html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have two date fields that I would like to make required but it's not adhering to the required attribute I'm placing on the control.  I read another stack post, but he only needed to add the ngModel to the input.  I already have the ngModel included and it's still letting me save without inserting Date.  It's working for my type="text" field...the 'Save' button is disabled until text is entered in the Destination field.  But it's not working for Date.

```
        <button ion-button text-only [disabled]="itineraryForm.invalid" 
          (click)="saveItinerary()">
          Save
       </button>

<ion-content class="cards-bg">
<ion-card padding class="ion-cards">
<ion-card-content padding>
<form #itineraryForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveItinerary()" 
autocomplete="off">
<div class="form-group">
    <ion-label for="destination">Destination</ion-label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="destination" 
      name="destination" required id="destination" placeholder="Enter 
     destination" #destin>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <ion-label >Trip dates</ion-label>
    <p style="float: left;">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="startDate" 
        name="startDate" required id="startDate" placeholder="Start" />
    </p>
    <p style="float: right;">
      <input  type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="endDate" 
        name="endDate" required id="endDate" placeholder="End"/>
    </p>
   </div>
    </form>
  </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
 </ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you link to the other question you read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#startDate="ngModel"` and `#endDate="ngModel"` to the input

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="startDate" 
    name="startDate" required id="startDate" placeholder="Start" #startDate="ngModel" />

<input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="endDate" 
    name="endDate" required id="endDate" placeholder="End" #endDate="ngModel" />
```

Then in your button, check if it is valid. for example

```
<button ion-button disabled *ngIf="!startDate.valid || !endDate.valid">Save</button>
<button ion-button *ngIf="startDate.valid && endDate.valid">Save</button>
```

here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/check-input-date-if-valid?file=pages/home/home.ts)